# Low *Tub Spout* Flow with All New Plumbing

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, plumbing-fixture, flow-rate

I just built a guest house myself. Everything is new, including the pipes. With no cartridge installed, and the stops open far as they go (~½” of threads showing), I get **~8 GPM** flow out of the **Delta** rough-in valve body (R10000-UNWS).

I’ve tried 3 cartridges (w/3/4" x 12" L brass nipple from the valve body to spout drop-ear) and all badly reduce flow from the tub spout (i.e. showerhead flow restrictors are irrelevant here).

1. (RP46463) reduces it to 1.9 GPM.
2. (same model) reduces it to 2.3 GPM.
3. (RP47201, higher flow) reduces it to ~3.4 GPM.

I’ve never installed a Delta cartridge before, but it seems straightforward, what could I be missing?

Comment: I have had many issues like this over the years with this brand . I refuse to use them now.  To your issue, is the hot and cold side both on equally, so this isn't a pressure balance issue?   I have had the Delta castings be restricted on one side and it caused the cartridge to reduce flow to compensate so as not to scald.

Comment: Check the "no-cartridge flow" from hot and cold separately, perhaps. I found a one-sided obstruction in the piping at one house (not the valve body) https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/49174/18078 - but I also give Delta a pass, generally.

Comment: Does this valve have screwdriver operated cut-off valves? If so, are they fully open? Is this valve for tub only or does it have a diverter for a shower?

Comment: RMDman: This is a pressure-balanced valve, yes. I've tried at various temps, including all-cold. 

Ecnerwal: Is there a way to do that without tearing open the wall? Either way, I think it's very, very unlikely... I have no flow problems at the water heater, which is 8' away from the valve in question, and I installed all this with brand-new piping days before I made this post.

Jim: Yes, and the shutoffs are all the way open. There is a separate diverter valve.