# low hot water pressure from just the shower

Tags: shower, water-pressure, mixing-valve

My hot water pressure is about half that of the cold.

This is what I've checked/done so far:

- Not the heater tank: The tub adjacent the shower has great hot water pressure
- Not the shower head: The cold water pressure is great
- Unlikely the cartridge: I **just** replaced the cartridge in an attempt to fix the pressure issue

This is everything I know about my setup that might help you diagnose the issue:

- I have a Moen 1222 cartridge
- I'm missing the temperature limit setter *(plastic piece that fits between cartridge and handle adapter)*
- To get a decent temperature (98F ish) I have to set the handle to about 10% of the way away from off

  - That means most (about 90%) of my water temperature is almost scalding hot with poor pressure
  - There's a very narrow window I can keep my handle in for comfortable temperature
- The water is fairly hard here
- In other questions on this site I've seen folks reference an anti-scalding mechanism that can be set but I can't seem to find it.

Here's a few pics to give you a sense of the equipment I'm working with:

[image: Shower Valve Left Side]
[image: Shower Valve Right Side]

I can't know for sure, but I think I have a Moen 2510 Four Port Cycle Valve like the one in the picture below:

[image: Moen 2510]

Comment: An aside: have you still got the retaining clip? You need it. (Though I don’t imagine that’s the root of your problem.)

Comment: Cold water pressure in my washer was low once. I have well water. It turned out to be that small rocks from the well pump blocked the water filter in the washer. Same thing happened with my kitchen sink. Maybe something is blocking your pipes?

Comment: Not related, but do you need the hot water to be scalding hot?  If not most/all hot water tanks have thermostats that can be turned down so the water does not burn skin in seconds.  Somewhere around 120(safe for skin) to 140(high)F

Comment: You can also install a tempering valve at the water heater itself, so the heater can be hot enough to reliably kill *Legionella* but the water to the taps is not scalding. As for possible problems, see this answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/49174/18078

Comment: Thank you all! I'll use that knowledge to try again this weekend and let you know how it went